Does Bitcoin Core store private keys
As of 2024 does bitcoin core store private keys. List open source wallets that doesn't store private keys

A wallet is essentially software that manages private keys. It’s not clear to me what you are asking for when you are asking for a "wallet that doesn’t store private keys"? Are you asking about watch-only wallets? Or did you mean to ask about wallets that don’t store the entire blockchain?

The primary purpose of any normal Bitcoin wallet is to store private keys.
By normal I mean non-custodial, the sort that Bitcoin's inventor intended us all to be using.
For me, it isn't possible for something be be a Bitcoin wallet and not store keys. The only exception would be a specialised watch-only wallet (so zero spendable balance) that doesn't automatically generate its own keys when first used.
